# Printing out the value from find_element_by_xpath

Tags: python, selenium

With the following HTML:

```
<td valign='top' align='center'><A HREF='https://www.daz3d.com/i/account/orderdetail?order=7886745'>7886745</A></TD>
```

This is part of a table, inside of a tr which is just one of many that I need to get that line out of.

The following code works to get the URL:

```
product_link = product_block.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'daz3d')] [1]");
print product_link
```

How do I show the actual text URL so I can use it to request that page?

Also, can I use a for loop to read all of the URL's into a table? If I do that, how can I be sure to NOT get the second URL in the tr (with the ">Reset<"), which is not needed?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `.get_attribute("href")`, as in:

```
print product_link.get_attribute("href")
```

Your second question is a little less clear... perhaps you are looking for the `find_elements_by_xpath()` which returns multiple elements?

Comment: print product_link.get_attribute("href") gives me the result:

Comment: print product_link.get_attribute("href") gives me the result: "http://www.daz3d.com/i/0/0?" - is there a way to expand that to get the entire URL? As to the second question find_elements_by_xpath() will probably work, I just need to figure out how to do it.